# glb Import Error due to IDProperty limitation

Tags: import, gltf

I am importing a .glb file into Blender and only the bone structure was imported, there are no model,texture or animation(which are supposedly there). I looked into it a little, but what is the best solution for this? I have other 4 models which also has the same issue. Thank you for any suggestions and solutions.

The error is as given:

```
Data are loaded, start creating Blender stuff
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 991, in execute
    return self.import_gltf2(context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 1005, in import_gltf2
    if self.unit_import(path, import_settings) == {'FINISHED'}:
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py", line 1025, in unit_import
    BlenderGlTF.create(gltf_importer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 42, in create
    BlenderGlTF._create(gltf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_gltf.py", line 49, in _create
    BlenderScene.create(gltf)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_scene.py", line 40, in create
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, 'root')
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 51, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 51, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_vnode(gltf, child)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 38, in create_vnode
    BlenderNode.create_object(gltf, vnode_id)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\imp\gltf2_blender_node.py", line 86, in create_object
    set_extras(obj, pynode.extras)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\com\gltf2_blender_extras.py", line 91, in set_extras
    blender_element[custom_property] = value
KeyError: 'the length of IDProperty names is limited to 63 characters'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the glTF importer. Importing fails if there is a long custom property name (Blender limits custom property names to 63 characters). I have reported it [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/1353). Hopefully it gets fixed soon.

In the meantime, you can apply a quick fix yourself which should let you import your models.

Open the file `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\2.92\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\blender\com\gltf2_blender_extras.py` in a text editor. Near the bottom you'll see this:

```
 try: 
     blender_element[custom_property] = value 
 except TypeError: 
     print('Error setting property %s to value of type %s' % (custom_property, type(value)))
```

Replace `TypeError` with `Exception` and save the file. Restart Blender, and you should now be able to import.

This will discard any custom properties with too-long names, so I hope you didn't need them for anything.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked well. One big worry out from my mind for now, tysm!